# Child transaction isolation level in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, isolation-level

Is it possible create child transaction with different from parent's isolation level ? E.g. with Castle's TransactionMode attributes :

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Requires, IsolationMode.ReadCommitted)]
void A()
{
   // select/update here

   B();

   // select/update here
}

[Transaction(TransactionMode.RequiresNew, IsolationMode.Serializeable)]
void B()
{
   // select/update here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what Castle does but NH doesnt have nested Transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Child transactions do not exist in NHibernate. The isolation mode of the first transaction requirement encountered will take precedence.